# What are the details of French Tax wrt pension withdrawal?

Tags: france, taxes, pension

A question about cashing in a UK pension.

I am reading that France has a generous tax treatment when cashing in a UK pension. As I understand it, the effective tax rate is 6.75% (taking in the 10% allowance) with an additional 9.1% in social charges for those enrolled in French healthcare. In my case, I will be applying for a CdS (or whatever the post-Brexit equivalent is) during 2020. I am not enrolled in CPAM, so would either look to enroll after cashing out my pension (but in the same tax year), or take out private healthcare for a year. Does anybody know if the social charge exemption "if not enrolled in public healthcare" applies to being enrolled on the exact date of the encashment, or if done in the same tax year?
I also understand that my withdrawal will initially be taxed by HMRC under UK rules, and that I will subsequently need to reclaim the UK tax using the DTT form.

If anybody has been through this process I would greatly value your experiences as it could be expensive if I get it wrong.